# iCarousel view not showing up in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, carousel

I am making an ios application on ipad and i am putting a iCarousel view in my application by the help of this script : 
http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/how-to-use-icarousel-view-controller-in-ios/
and when i complete all the steps and run this application on ipad it doesn't show me anything but when i run this application on iphone it works properly.

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: You need to give us some code and be more specific about what isn't working before we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `else` code every time you find this  :
      if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

so that you define the frame and views fro iPad version.

**UPDATE:**

For example :

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
rec.size.width = 250;
rec.size.height = 250;
}else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
rec.size.width = 500;
rec.size.height = 500;

}
```

Comment: search in your code every where you find "if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone" add else{ //Do Something for iPad  }

Comment: what should i write in do something for ipad ?

Comment: please mark it as solution if it is helping you. thanks and you are welcome.